# Horizontal autoscroll, how to make it loop?

Tags: android

I have implemented a horizontal scroll view using this [Vertically AutoScrolling Textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921844/vertically-autoscrolling-textview)..
but there is no description of how to make the text scroll in a loop..Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Add this in xml:

```
<ScrollView 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:id="@+id/sc">


         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Thanks Christian but I am trying to get my text to scroll downwards automatically I am able to scroll horizontally fine."
            android:textSize="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txt"  />

     </ScrollView>
```

And this in your activity:

```
ScrollView scrollView=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc);
        scrollView.post(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, scrollView.getBottom());
            }
        });
```

Comment: <HorizontalScrollView 
         <TextView 
             android:text="Thanks Christian but I am trying to get my text to scroll downwards automatically I am able to scroll horizontally fine."
             android:textSize="50dp"
             android:focusable="true"
             android:singleLine="true" 
              android:ellipsize="marquee"
             android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
             android:scrollHorizontally="true"   
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
             android:id="@+id/mark"
             />
     </HorizontalScrollView>

Comment: what is difference in your code and mine. i hv just given the actual code through which the requirement fulfills and you have just inserted textview and horizontal tags,thats it!!

Comment: Yes, that is what is confusing me too.....I did not really get it why it is not working.....

Comment: i have included android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever" this line and i have posted data after implementation only.its working fine.Do you think i will supply you the code that does not work??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13769/discussion-between-kunal-shah-and-akashg)

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that by just scrolling the scrollView back to the top when it reaches the bottom. This will make your ScrollView loop infinitely.

something like this-

```
public void scrollDown(final ScrollView v){
new CountDownTimer(2000, 20) { 

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
        if((2000 - millisUntilFinished)==v.getBottom())
              millisUntilFinished=2000;
        v.scrollTo((int) (0,2000 - millisUntilFinished)); 
    } 

    public void onFinish() { 

    } 
 }.start(); }
```

i havent tried it myself though, but the logic should work.

Comment: if you think its right, you might want to accept the answer :-)

Comment: Vinay, I did horizontal scroll view using the above logic....Now I am trying out your logic... will give it a try and accept it....

Comment: change it to this this -
`if(((int)(2000 - millisUntilFinished))==v.getBottom())`
and
 `v.scrollTo(0,(int)(2000 - millisUntilFinished)); `

Comment: I tried that too, it does not work....and it should be v.getRight() as this is a horizontal scrollview, is not it?