# Is there an easy way to automatically scroll a TextView vertically like film credits?

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView with an arbitrary amount of text. My goal is to have it automatically scroll from completely past the bottom of the view, all the way through, and completely off the top at a fixed rate independent of the text length. I currently have something mostly working with a linear Scroller, but it's a huge mess. The Scroller only works in terms of a scrolling range at a fixed duration, so I'm having to calculate that based on how many lines are in the TextView, the line height, and how many lines per second I want to scroll.

Consequently I can't do anything until after the view finishes sizing itself, pausing and resuming the scroll is a mess, etc. The code just looks terrible and I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to achieve this effect without jumping through hoops and very likely introducing unforeseen bugs?

Thanks!

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6387293/420015)

Comment: @aneal While the question is the same, does your link provide an answer?

Comment: Yeah, that link isn't really helping me much. But now, I did see [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921844/vertically-autoscrolling-textview?rq=1) pop up in the related links for _this_ question after posting, which is the same thing. (This topic is tricky to research because most of the hits are questions about _instantaneously_ scrolling to an offset, which isn't what I need.)

So that solution looks a bit less messy than what I'm doing currently, but it still doesn't feel totally correct.

Comment: In the meantime I'm currently looking at the TextView and Scroller source code to see if I can just code up a clean, reusable Scroller that I can drop in anywhere rather than wrestling with the existing Scroller class or putting ScrollViews on timers. If I come up with something usable I'll post the code.

Comment: Alright, so currently I have something a lot less messy by subclassing TextView and overriding onDraw(). I calculate a scrollTo() offset based on an elapsed time in milliseconds * pixelsPerSecond / 1000f, then do invalidate() to make sure the view continues animating if the integer offset comes out to less than one pixel since the last redraw. I don't know if that's a "good" solution though so I'm leaving the question open for a bit in case I or someone else can come up with a better answer.